# Сколько можно создать выходов из цикла (while)?

Tags: swift, while

Всем привет.

В swift у оператора while есть 1 выход прописываемый в начале.

```
var a = 0
 while a != 5 {
 a = a + 1 
}
```

Можно ли задать 2 условия выхода из цикла?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сколько угодно условий можно:

```
var a = 0
while (a < 15 && a != 2)
{
    a = a + 1
    if (a == 10) 
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сколько угодно:

```
while (a == 5) || (a == 10) || (a < 8) {   
    a = a + 1
}
```